# Remove windows update available notificiation

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Dears,,

Could anyone help to remove the pending updates in windows 10.
[image]

Comment: Defer the updates in the settings app.

Comment: Could you please share the steps?

Comment: See this [article](https://m.windowscentral.com/how-defer-windows-10-updates).

Comment: @Mr.Ali - Whether you want to remove the Windows Update notification only, or do you want to stop the downloads too? Remember that if things are managed with the help of Group Policy in your organisation, you'd not be able to directly control it without your system-administrator's intervention!

Comment: I encountered this issue last week.  I restarted my system and the problem went away

Comment: with **Windows update minitool** you can hide updates like in older Windows versions

Comment: I stopped windows update service and restarted the system, but the updates keep appearing